# Magento - New product attributes created by backend not visible

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento, magento-1.7

i've created trough backend two new product's attributes, both locally and on test server. while locally i' able to see new attributes in product details, on test server i dont see any on the two new attributes. i've tried several times to reindex data, clear cache, cancel and recreate those attributes, with same configuration that i have locally, but it didn't work, i can't see my new attributes. what i can check?
here's two screenshot:

locally:
[image]

test server:
[image]

Comment: How you insert this attribute?? Show us the code.

Comment: solved, my mistake, just an admin interface question: i didn't add attributes to attribute set. thanx anyway

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any attribute you are adding, must be assigned to some attribute set.

So you have to go to **Catalog -> Attribut -> Manage Attributsets** every time after your create a new attribute and assign it to a attribute set.

Then will it will appear in the product entry form if you choose the right attribute while adding products.

Comment: And if you create a new heading in the attribute set, you can get it to have its own tab as well in product management. Won't show till you have at least one attribute in the heading.